# FCM with NextJs

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, next.js

I am trying to integrate FCM with next.js ..but its showing the following error. Can anyone please help me with the next.config.js file?

```
FirebaseError: Messaging: We are unable to register the default service worker. Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope') with script ('http://localhost:3000/firebase-messaging-sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script. (messaging/failed-service-worker-registration).
    at WindowController.eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/messaging/dist/index.esm.js:1053:45)
    at step (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:124:23)
    at Object.eval [as throw] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:105:53)
    at rejected (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/tslib/tslib.es6.js:96:65)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to configure the next.config.js, you just have to add the serviceWorker in the Public folder with the name of firebase-messaging-sw.js

They mention the following in the documentation:

> The messaging service requires a firebase-messaging-sw.js file. Unless you already have  a firebase-messaging-sw.js file, create an empty file with that name and place it in the  root of your domain before retrieving a token. You can add meaningful content to the  file later in the client configuration process.

Visit: [Access the registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client)

your serviceWorker should look like this:

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-messaging.js');
 
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: 'api-key',
  authDomain: 'project-id.firebaseapp.com',
  databaseURL: 'https://project-id.firebaseio.com',
  projectId: 'project-id',
  storageBucket: 'project-id.appspot.com',
  messagingSenderId: 'sender-id',
  appId: 'app-id',
  measurementId: 'G-measurement-id',
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();



messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions);
});
```

Remember use ENV on your initializeApp

Comment: thanks a lot, I just had to move `firebase-messaging-sw.js` to `public` folder

Comment: How do youuse ENV on your initializeApp? Having trouble passing env vars to the public folder.

Answer (score 2):

[Example with nextjs, Firebase V9 cloud messaging](https://github.com/ivanandresdiaz/firebase-v9-cloud-messaging)

Generate VapidKey
add config variables of your project
After, you execute de npm run dev. It will appear the token in the console, you can use that token to send a [test message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message). and it will send the foreground and background notification.